# How to index filtered records rendering the same view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would choose the right way to proceed when I have to index "filtered" records rendering the *same* views.

That is, I have articles that are created by an user and those that are not created by that user, and both can be indexed by that user. Since I have to display those records "filtering" articles that are created or not by the user, I thought that a way to handle this situation is the following (in the `ArticlesController` class and by rendering the same view):

```
def index
  @articles =
    case params[:filter]
      when nil
        Article.all
      when "created_by_me"
        Article.created_by(@current_user)
    end

   ...
end
```

Is the above the "right" way to proceed? Or, maybe, I should implement a new controller action like, for example, `index_my`? Or, maybe, something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to add a filter param to index than build several different index actions. It also allows you the flexibility to add more filters without having to add even more duplicate index actions.